# My SD card that I use with my truck's dash-cam says disk full. but disk is blank

Tags: webcam, micro-sd, memory-card

I use Ubuntu 17.04 and the dash cam in my truck records to a SD card. When I put it in my dash cam it says card full, but when I put it on my desktop it says it's empty. I just want it to be like new again, no partitions, etc.

How can I make the card work in my dash cam?

Comment: Some SD cards are formatted exfat. I am not sure if exfat support is on by default in your version of Ubuntu, which has reached its end of life. Thus, questions about Ubuntu 17.04 are off-topic now.

Comment: Can you include the output of `lsblk` with the card inserted in the computer? [Edit] your question to include this information

Comment: @user68186 17.04 is EOL, but the question doesn't feel specific to 17.04 to me...

Comment: @vidarlo I am not sure the problem is Ubuntu related at all. The problem may be with the dash-cam or the specific SD card.

Comment: That I agree with. My guess is wrong file system or files in the .Trash-folder - which may be related to Ubuntu...

Comment: In a terminal window, `journalctl --follow`. Then insert your SD card. Read the log messages printed by `journalctl --follow` for hints.

Comment: I am reformatting now...

Comment: I was finally able to reformat, up and running now. Thanks to all I appreciate it.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the card is fried. I have to buy another one,

Comment: I had to update this because someone might need this answer. I want to share this information. The Dashcam is the Papago GoSafe 260. There can be a problem depending on what kind of SD card you use.  There can be problems if you use SD cards that are in my opinion some of the best SD cards. I would never have guessed that a sandisk card would be a problem, but it does seem to be the case. Here is a link to which SD cards you should and shouldn't use with this product. Thanks to everybody who helped me with this problem. http://us.papagoinc.com/support/knowledgebase/#sd card